# How to erase UIBezirePath Drawing on touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, uibezierpath, erase

I am using `UIBezirePath` for drawing. Most of my research on this shows that to erase points you need to stroke with a background colour.

This will give the true effect on iPad without any doubt but i am rendering drawing on the context and making a large size *PNG* from this. This approach will create a problem whenever i make *PNG*.

Can any one suggest some better solution?

Comment: have you tried stroke with clear color

Comment: It won't erase. Stroke below it will appear as it is. No change!